# Error with recording membership payment offline

Tags: civimember

Is anyone aware of any issue with trying to record a membership payment offline?
WE are running CiviCRM 4.7.11

Click on and existing Membership and edit membership.

Click on the checkbox that says Record Membership Payment.
None of the fields  to record the membership payment are being displayed such as amount, financial type etc.

If you then click on the Send Confirmation and Receipt checkbox, 
 and then click 'Save' it of course gives an error saying Please enter the financial Type.

Not sure what is going on as we have not come across this issue before

Update:Just checked with Civihosting and they have confirmed its a bug.
Has anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: This doesn't sound so much like it is a question about receipting working intermittently, as much as 'why is Financial Type required' (which it clearly is), or perhaps 'how do i end up with contributions recorded without a financial type?' Can you either shed more light or refocus your question on that. other thing to try would be to see if you can replicate on demo site.

Comment: Hi Pete.Sorry for the confusion.  Our client has been saying there is an issue with receipts only being sent out intermittently.  After trying to investigate the issue, and taking your advice to check the demo site we found that there is a bug when trying to record a membership payment in our client's version.  None of the fields to record payment are appearing such as amount, financial type etc. This was confirmed by civihosting.  Will try and see if this bug can be fixed.  This is probably causing the issue with receipts not being sent out all the time.

Comment: okay. what can you do to clean up this ticket then? rename it? Delete it?

Comment: Ive edited the ticket to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I just confirmed the bug in http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. This means not fixed yet. I take a look on https://issues.civicrm.org and I have not found any related error.

You can see guideline [Bug Reporting](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting) and report this issue.

Comment: The bug has already been reported here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19850 and it seems that some work has been done to address it.

Answer (score 1):

Bug was addressed for upcoming CiviCRM 5.1 release. You can see more info to the related PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11087 and reported issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19850.